# Setting CKReference is not saved

Tags: ios, cloudkit

In CloudKit dashboard, record type `User` has a field called `Boards` of type `Reference (List)`, and record type `Board` has a field called `User` of type `Reference`. This is a sample of code indicating how I am attempting to link a `Board` to a `User`:

```
CKReference *reference = [[CKReference alloc] initWithRecord:userRecord action:CKReferenceActionDeleteSelf];
[boardRecord setObject:reference forKey:@"User"];
```

If I `NSLog(@"%@", [boardRecord objectForKey:@"User"]);` before and after setting the object, I get a result of `(null)` before, and after it is a `CKReference` object with the same `recordName` as the `User`. But in CloudKit dashboard, the `Board` does not update its `User` field, and the `User` does not have a reference added to its `Boards` reference list, so when I subsequently query the `User` for associated `Board`s I do not receive any results. I cannot understand why the reference is correctly set according to what is logged, but does not actually get saved.

Here is the code used to save to iCloud:

```
+ (void)saveEntity:(CloudKitEntity *)entity completion:(void (^)(NSError * _Nonnull))completion {
    [[self privateDatabase] saveRecord:entity.record completionHandler:^(CKRecord * _Nullable record, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (completion) {
            completion(error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Logging the error revealed an error that "Server Record Changed", which I think means the server version of the record is newer than the local version. But I don't know what to do about this since I have just cleaned/rebuilt, deleted the app and rebuilt/reinstalled and received the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to fetch both of the records again using their `recordID`s, then set create the `CKReference` and set it using the *re-fetched* objects, and then save the re-fetched object. Why it needs to be this complicated I have no idea.